# To view video/audio properties like Resolution, Bitrate, Frame Rate, Aspect Ratio, Duration, etc. in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, properties, video

We are creating an intranet site in SharePoint Online, basically to share files between different teams.

Want to know is there a way to see the details of a video file - like Video/audio properties - Resolution, Bitrate, Frame Rate, Aspect Ratio, Duration, etc. after uploading into SharePoint online?

[In dropbox, we have an option "View all details" to see all mentioned above - looking for same kind of option].

Answer (score 0):

There is "Details Pane" in SharePoint online modern experience. But I believe it will not show all these details of video files. You can see the type (extension) or size of video file.

Also, there is no out of the box web part which will show these video details in SharePoint online modern experience.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, these attributes will not be retrieved automatically after uploading.

It is necessary to create columns for videos and manually fill in these field values.